# Recover ubuntu data from hard drive in dual boot ubuntu/windows hard drive

Tags: dual-boot, data-recovery

My computer is broken so i want to remove the hard drive and place it as an external hard drive via Usb on anothercomputer. Is it possible to recover the data from the partition of ubuntu in a dual boot hard drive?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `live-USB` with a Linux distribution on it and boot with the `live environment` and from here you can access your hdd.

Edit: you can't do this with windows because for Microsoft, windows is the only OS available  in the world so naturally windows can't handle `ext` Linux partition format.